# Rails has_many and belongs_to checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

I have the following models:

vendor: stores details of vendors

```
has_many :vendor_business_type, foreign_key: "vendor_id"
```

vendor_business_type: stores reference to vendors and the business_types they have

```
belongs_to :vendor
```

business_type: stores type of businesses

I am making a new/create form as below:

```
<%= form_for @vendor %>
    <% BusinessType.where(:business_id=>"5").each do |business_type| %>
        <%= check_box_tag "vendor[vendor_business_type_attributes][business_type_ids][]", business_type.id %>
        <%= business_type.business_type_name %>
    <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

vendor#new

```
@vendor=Vendor.new()
@vendor.build_school
@vendor.vendor_business_type.build()
```

vendor_params

```
params.require(:vendor).permit(:vendor_business_type_attributes [:business_type_ids=> []])
```

This gives me an error: no implicit conversion of Hash into Integer

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
 params.require(:vendor).permit(:vendor_business_type_attributes => { :business_type_ids => [] })
```

Since the business_type_id is specified inside brackets in your form, it becomes a hash attribute, not part of an array.

Comment: Now it is giving me an error:
no implicit conversion of String into Integer

This error is coming in vendors#create in line
@vendor=Vendor.new(vendor_params)

Comment: Can you paste what your request params look like in the logs?